# php code update split and count not working

Tags: php, split, count

I made some code updates from 5.6 to 7.4.11 and this section of code stopped working, Its not tossing an error so im a little unclear where I went wrong.

Original code

```
<?
 $mapdesc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the_mapdesc');
 if (count($maxmapdesclength) > 0 )
 { 
  if (strlen($mapdesc[0]) > $maxmapdesclength) $mapdesc[0] = substr($mapdesc[0], 0, $maxmapdesclength-3) . '...';
    $arrmapdesc = split("\n", $mapdesc[0]);
    $mymapdesc = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<count($arrmapdesc) && $i<3; $i++)
     $mymapdesc .= $arrmapdesc[$i] . '<br />';
    
    print $mymapdesc;
 }
```

Updated code

```
<?
 $mapdesc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the_mapdesc');
 // if (count($maxmapdesclength) > 0 )
 if (is_countable($maxmapdesclength) && count($maxmapdesclength) > 0 )
 { 
  if (strlen($mapdesc[0]) > $maxmapdesclength) $mapdesc[0] = substr($mapdesc[0], 0, $maxmapdesclength-3) . '...';
    $arrmapdesc = explode("\n", $mapdesc[0]);
    $mymapdesc = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<count($arrmapdesc) && $i<3; $i++)
     $mymapdesc .= $arrmapdesc[$i] . '<br />';
    
    print $mymapdesc;
 }
```

Comment: So WHAT is the error?

Comment: the error is that nothing is displayed, error logs are clean, its looking like the issue is with the `is_countable` line aka `print $mymapdesc;` did not output anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there's something wrong with your usage of `$maxmapdesclength`.

In the *if* statement, you are treating it as a Countable|array, and within the `substr` function you are then expecting it to act like a number.

Comment: If I keep the explode and revert back to count the code works but troughs a php warning